# Wordpress - targeting images in content

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have the following code in my wordpress theme, single-post page (the page where single posts are displayed).

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"<?php post_class('col-md-12'); ?>>
<div class="container">

    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header>

    <?php
        $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
        $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 1200, 720, true ); //resize & crop the image
    ?>

    <?php if($image) : ?>
    <img class="img-responsive singlepic" src="<?php echo $image ?>"/>
    <?php endif; ?> 

    <?php if ( $post->post_type == 'data-design' && $post->post_status == 'publish' ) {

if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        $class = "post-attachment mime-" . sanitize_title( $attachment->post_mime_type );
        $thumbimg = wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail-size', true );
        echo '<li class="' . $class . ' data-design-thumbnail">' . $thumbimg . '</li>'; 
    }
}  
}
?>

<div class="entry-content">

    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php
        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'web2feel' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
    ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->

</div>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

It puts the post-title then featured-image as a large image then posts the content, and then the rest.

I want to target the images in the content, and display them the same way as the featured-image is displayed.

*NOTE - changes to the 'if ( $attachments ) { ...' function doesn't change anything (nor does completely removing it) so I am not certain what that part does. the only code that affects the content is when it is called ( '')

Comment: You can do it without php, in the editor just set the same css classes as the featured-image to the images in the post. Or you can copy the css properties of those css classes into `.entry-content img`.

Comment: The php code $php if($image) sets the image size/cropping, etc so wouldn't there need to be php involved to follow the same class as featured-image? Your way works, but the quality is very low (its brought in small in the post php (even though its a large image) and adding 100% width just scales it up in low quality

Comment: figured it out! a mix of what you said and a couple code changes fixed it, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes ago I used to following code to strip off all the images in my content area and then display them separately apart from the contents. This might help you.

In your `functions.php` file -

```
function stripe_images_from_content($content){

$images = array();  
$subject = $content;

$subject = preg_replace('~<img [^\>]*\ />~', '', $subject);
$subject = preg_replace('~\[caption[^\]]*\][^\]]*\]~', '', $subject);

$image_urls = array();

$match_count = preg_match_all( '/<img.*src=["\']([^"\']*)["\'].*\/>/', $content, $image_urls );

if (is_numeric($match_count) && $match_count > 0) {

    if( is_array($image_urls[1]) and count($image_urls[1]) > 0 ){

        foreach( $image_urls[1] as $i ){

            $featured_image_url = $i;               
            $image_id = get_attachment_id_from_src( $featured_image_url );

            if (! is_numeric($image_id)) {

                $match_count = preg_match( '/(.*)-\d+x\d+(\.(jpg|png|gif))/', $featured_image_url, $matches );

                if (is_numeric($match_count) && $match_count > 0) {
                    $base_image_url = $matches[1] . $matches[2];

                    $images[] = get_attachment_id_from_src( $base_image_url );
                }
            }
            else{
                $images[] = $image_id;
            }

        }

    }       

}

$data = new stdClass();

$data->images = $images;
$data->content = $subject;

return $data;
```

}

What this function does is get all the images inserted in the content area of a post and strip them off. Then return the image(s) and the content without image.

in your `single.php` file-

```
$content = stripe_images_from_content(get_the_content());
```

Now you need to do two things. `$content->images` contains all the images inserted in the post content area. And `$content->content` holds the raw content images stripped off. **First** you need to use `$content->images` wisely where you want to display your images and **second** replace the `the_content()` function with `echo wpautop($content->content);`

Hope this might help you.

Comment: interesting approach. I managed to get it working for my needs, but this is definitely a strategy I'll be keeping in my back pocket for another project. Thank you!